# How can I compare the char input in C for seasons

Tags: c

I need to write a program to take input from the user. The first is a char named inputMonth and the second is an int named inputDay. The program needs to compare the input and determine the seasons. The range is:

Spring: March 20 - June 20
Summer: June 21 - September 21
Autumn: September 22 - December 20
Winter: December 21 - March 19

So far I've attempted to get the winter months but the program has no output. The example input of April 11 would output Spring

```
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
   char inputMonth[50];
   int inputDay;
   
   scanf("%s", inputMonth); 
   scanf("%d", &inputDay); 
   
   if (inputMonth <= 3 && inputDay <= 19) {
      printf("Winter");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `inputMonth <= 3` -- you are comparing an array against an integer constant, what do you expect to happen here?

Comment: Always enable the compiler warnings. They will make evident most of the issues present in the code: `gcc -Wall seasons.c -o seasons`.

Comment: You are comparing `int` with `char*` so expect any magic to happen. Also, you should avoid using `scanf()` to read input. Use `fgets()` instead and parse the result (if necessary) with `sscanf()`.

Comment: regarding: `if (month <= 3 && inputDay <= 19) {`  This contains a logic error.  For instance what about February 21?  I.E.  Most months have no need to check the day, but for those months that are split between different seasons,, an additional check for the specific day is needed

Answer (score 2):

`inputMonth` is a string, and you read it as a string, but then you compare it to a number (you should enable more warnings in your compiller to catch similar bugs).

Either read `inputMonth` as a number (similary to `inputDay`) or you will have to rewrite month comparison (I suggest you look at `strcmp` function).

Comment: After looking more into my book, I think its trying to force me to combine the `if` function with `strcmp`. The default template for the assignment had set `inputMonth` as `char`. I thought `int` made more sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical error. You must convert the string `inputMonth` into a number before make a numeric check (`month <= 3`).
Here's a fixed version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
   char inputMonth[50];
   int inputDay;

   scanf("%s", inputMonth);
   scanf("%d", &inputDay);

   long month = strtol(inputMonth, (char **)NULL, 10);

   if (month <= 3 && inputDay <= 19) {
      printf("Winter\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

But why not to use an `int` for `inputMonth` as you've done for `inputDay`?

This is a complete implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
month_number (char *name)
{
  char *months[] = {
    "jan", "feb", "mar", "apr",
    "may", "jun", "jul", "aug",
    "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"
  };

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof (months) / sizeof (months[0]); i++)
    if (!strcmp (months[i], name))
      return i+1;

  return -1;
}

int
main (void)
{
  char inputMonth[50];
  int day, month;

  printf ("Enter month: ");
  scanf ("%s", inputMonth);
  printf ("Enter day: ");
  scanf ("%d", &day);

  month = month_number (inputMonth);
  if (month < 0)
    {
      fprintf (stderr,
               "unknown month \"%s\", must be une of 'jan', 'feb', ...\n",
               inputMonth);
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  /*
   * Spring: March 20 - June 20
   * Summer: June 21 - September 21
   * Autumn: September 22 - December 20
   * Winter: December 21 - March 19
   */

  if ((month == 3 && day >= 20) || (month > 3 && month < 6)
      || (month == 6 && day <= 20))
    printf ("Spring\n");
  else if ((month == 6 && day >= 21) || (month > 6 && month < 9)
           || (month == 9 && day <= 21))
    printf ("Summer\n");
  else if ((month == 9 && day >= 22) || (month > 9 && month < 12)
           || (month == 12 && day <= 20))
    printf ("Autumn\n");
  else
    printf ("Winter\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The default template for the assignment had set to inputMonth as char. I would have set it to an int if I was writing it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

As other comment says, inputMonth is an character array allocated in the stack.
So

```
inputMonth[i] => char
inputMonth => char *
```

As inputMonth is pointing to stack memory, it's value will be much bigger then 3.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int month_name_to_number(char * name) {
    char *months[] = {"jan", "feb", "mar", "april",
                    "may", "june", "july", "aug",
                    "sept", "oct", "nov", "dec"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        if (!strcmp(months[i], name))
            return i;
}

int main(void) {
   char inputMonth[50];
   int inputDay;
   int month;
   
   scanf("%s", inputMonth); 
   scanf("%d", &inputDay); 
   
   month = month_name_to_number(inputMonth);
   printf("month %d, day %d\n", month, inputDay);
   if (month <= 3 && inputDay <= 19) {
      printf("Winter");
   }
   return 0;
}
```